ReactJS Image viewable on localhost (yarn start) but can't view after build (yarn build)
I inspect the network tab and see that the image contentType being changed to text/html on build version:
build img
The local yarn start version is fine: start img
The image path is correct and the image is present in public folder and build folder: build folder
public folder
And it only happened with that image in some pages (unit 7), all other pages is fine, but i don't have any code to seperate between units
My img render code:
exerciseKey ? (
          <img
            src={exerciseKey}
            alt="..."
            style={{ paddingTop: 25, paddingRight: 10 }}
          />
        ) : (
          <div className="mt-5 d-flex justify-content-center text-info display-3">
            Students’ own answers
          </div>
        )

exerciseKey example: exerciseKey: "img/FriendsPlus/Page49/Key/E1answerKey.png"
I tried npm build, yarn build, deploy on another vps using nginx (currently using firebase), clear build folder before rebuild, build on another pc, add ${process.env.PUBLIC_URL} before img path, but all the same
Solved: It's just typo, and windows is case-insensitive

Just a typo combined with a case-sensitive filesystem in production... E1answerkey.png (lowercase "k") is your file but you're requesting E1answerKey.png (uppercase "K")

@Phil Omg, the localhost still viewable make me don't check typo carefully, my other partners don't notice them too :)) But why yarn start still regcognize the file, is it case insensitive?

Yep. In general, macOS and Windows filesystems are case-insensitive whereas most Linux filesystems are case-sensitive.
